# Slutsky theorem with multiple types of convergence

Tags: analysis, statistics, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables and that  $X_n \ \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} \ \mu$

We know $\displaystyle \frac{n}{n-1} \ \overset{}{\longrightarrow} \ 1$, so can we apply the Slutsky's theorem here and claim that:

$\displaystyle \left( \frac{n}{n-1} \right) \left( X_n \right) \ \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} \ (1)  (\mu) = \mu $

My concern is that the two sequences are of different types of convergence, so I'm not sure if I can put them together.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: $\frac{n}{n-1} \to 1$ in probability. You can think of $(n)$ as a sequence of degenerate r.v.s

Comment: @Calculon Thank you! And in this sense, can I say that convergence implies convergence in probability?

Comment: Yup. The usual sense of convergence is obviously stronger than almost sure convergence, which implies conv in prob

Comment: @Calculon Thank you so much for your help!